# Node.js http.globalAgent.maxSockets not respected

Tags: javascript, node.js

## Issue

When a request, having the `response` event registered, is aborted the `maxSockets` limit is no longer respected. It seems to happen only when the response contains some data.

**Tested versions:** v4.1.1 and v5.1.0

## Client

```
var http = require('http');

http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var request = http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080', function () {
        // just register a listener...
    });
    request.setTimeout(1000, function () {
        console.log('T')
        this.abort();
    });
}
```

## Server

```
require('http').createServer(function (reqest, response) {
    console.log('R');
    response.end('hello');
}).listen(8080);
```

## Behavior

The server output is:

```
$ node server.js 
R
R
R
# 1s timeout here...
R
R
R
R
R
R
# 1s timeout here...
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
# 1s timeout here...
[...]
```

Is seems that every time, `maxSockets` is multiplied by 2 (3, 6, 12, 24, etc.), even though its value does not change. I was expecting groups of 3 instead.

*Resuming* the response, as opposed to aborting the request, works fine in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a [bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4050) with Node.js.